# JobIntentService : Unable to schedule jobs with other apps - Oreo

Tags: android, intentservice, android-backup-service, android-8.1-oreo

I am trying to schedule a job to `JobIntentService` of another app(2 different processes).

```
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                   "com.anotherapp.service.MyJobIntentService");

JobIntentService.enqueueWork(this,componentName,100,new Intent());
```

which gives the below exception.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: uid 10000 cannot schedule job to
>   "com.anotherapp.service"

SO the question is, are we able to communicate to `JobIntentService` outside our app ?

Note: With in the app it's possible to schedule jobs.

Comment: I don't know if this is possible due to security reasons. An alternative way could be to throw a custom broadcast from the first app which the second app can read and schedule the job itself.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong on this but i believe that in order to have apps call other apps(automatically) you must have root permissions when executing said app.

Because it's a rather suspicious behaviour maybe even your antivirus might inhibit its execution(if you are running on a real phone that is) i believe in the case of simulated ones this shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Service or Receiver for communicate the two apps.

Comment: In android 8 this dont work, if you have solution for this problem share please

Answer (score 0):

> only the app itself (or shared uid participant) can schedule a job that runs one of the app's services

I think you can send a broadcast to the target process. When the target process receive it, enqueue what you want.